# Are multi-pages phonegap apps prevented from being published on Stores? and How to publish it?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm developing an application using Cordova/PhoneGap and of course when I finish I'd like to publish it on Play Store.

So my question is, How Can I Publish my app on the store? Is there a specific way or specific rules to follow while programming or publishing? I searched a lot but got nothing useful yet.

And another question.
what if my app is a multi pages app? not only `index.html`? is that something will prevent it from being published on the store?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How Can I Publish my app on the store?...

http://www.adamwadeharris.com/sign-publish-phonegap-app-google-play-store-windows/

> what if my app is a multi pages app? not only index.html?...

it's totally ok check some apps of mine on the market

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Brilliant+App

Comment: Great to know, In the documentation of phonegap I figured that I'll create a keystore and I'll upload it to my account on the cloud compiler, then when I build an app I'll choose a keystore from the ones I uploaded before to be related with the app I'm compiling .. Is that it? Did I understand it right?

Comment: yup... don't forget to mark my answer as the right one ;)